# Display half-a-day event in dayview

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

How can I display half-a-day events in a slot duration of 1 day?

```
slotDuration: {days: 1},
```

[image]

I tried to set the duration to 12 hours but then the view gets very cluttered caused by the double weekday name and the shown time. My goal is it to keep the view as clean as possible.

Comment: Set the slotDuration to 12 hours but then use slotLabelInterval to space the labels at 1 day still

Comment: @ADyson That indeed worked! I used the following settings in my config now:


`slotDuration: {hours: 12},

slotLabelInterval: {hours: 24},`